# If $a\geq b$, is it enough to prove $a=b$?

Tags: real-analysis, logic

If $a\geq b$, is it enough to prove $a=b$?

Hello,

i was wondering whether it is enough to show $a=b$. Since "$\geq$" means "greater **OR** equal to.

Wouldn't it be enough to prove one of them?

Comment: Yes, if you prove that $a=b$ you have proved that $a \geq b$.

Comment: The grammar in this question is really confusing. What does "If $P$, is it enough to prove $Q$?" even mean? — Does the edit reflect the intended meaning of OP?

Comment: Grrr, you changed the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, it was I who edited the question.

Comment: @user1551: even worse !

Comment: Rolled back changes that may or may not reflect the OPs intention.

Comment: Whether "it is enough"  depends on what you're trying to do. What are you trying to do??? (My _guess_ is "If $a\ge b$" was supposed to be "If we're trying to show $a\ge b$.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $3\ge2$ is true, but $3=2$ is not.

---

**Update:**

The question (original and edited) is ambiguous.

If you can prove $a=b$, this indeed proves $a\ge b$.

If you can prove $a>b$, this indeed proves $a\ge b$.

---

In real situations, both the proofs of $a=b$ and $a>b$ can fail.

E.g.

$$x=t^2\implies x\ge0$$ is a true statement.

But you can't prove

$$x=0$$ nor $$x>0.$$

Comment: Yves, doesn't $a=b \implies a\geq b \land b\geq a$?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: yes, and ?

Comment: Is $2\geq 2$ a valid statement?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: valid and true.

Comment: Ok, that's all i wanted to know.